# Binding events to dynamically added elements in jQuery Modal Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery Modal PoUp](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default). I have a number of textboxes and buttons that I display within the popup. There is a button, `btnaddlot` to which I want to add a click event, but I am unable to do so.

```
var varLot = '<b>Lot Title: </b> <input type="text" id="txtlottitle" style="width:500px;" value="Lot Title" /> <textarea id="lotstextarea"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="ADD" id="btnAddLot" class="bluebutton" style="float:right;"/> <br /> <div id="lottypes"> <table> <tr> <td style="width:width: 80px;"><b>Lot Types: </b></td><td> <table> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdoitemlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Item Lot" /></td><td>Item Lot - Bid at Item level, compete at Lot level(collect item pricing during bidding.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdobasketlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket"/></td><td>Basket - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(collect item pricing post bidding.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdobasketwithnoitem" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket with No Items" /></td><td> Basket with No Items - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(Do not collect item pricing.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> </table></td> </tr> </table> </div> <hr /> <table> <tr> <td>Improve Bid By: </td><td><span id="lblimprovebidsby"></span></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span id="lblbiddecrement">Bid Decrement</span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtbiddecrement" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Protect the lead bid with front buffer of : </span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtfrontbuffer" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Protect the lead bid with back buffer of : </span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtbackbuffer" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Can participants submit tie bids : </span></td><td><span id="lbltiebids"></span></td> </tr> </table>'

var section = $(this);
$(this).toggleClass("expand");
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog(
        { width: 800 }, 
        { height: 600 }, 
        { modal: true }, 
        { 
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").html(varLot);
                $("textarea").jqte();
                //$("#dialog").append($(section).html());
            },
            buttons: { 
                "OK": function () { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                } 
            } 
        }
    );
```

It seems that the only way to add button is like `buttons: { "OK": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }` BUT I want to add click event to btnAddLot and may be later on I might want to add events to radio buttons that i have within the popup. How do I do this?

```
$('#pricingdiv').on('click', '#btnAddLot', function (e) {
    alert('hey');
    e.preventDefault();   

});
```

Comment: Assuming `#pricingdiv` is in the DOM on load (and not appended with the popup) your second example should work fine. Note however, that the way you instantiate your popup is incorrect. The properties should all be part of a *single* object, not each defined within their own. Also you appear to have some mis-matched braces.

Comment: #pricingdiv is not dynamically added. It is already present. It's not working. I just found out that if i move the click event bindding code withing `open` section of modal pop up. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the html as regular code, then you can set the onclick right off the bat. Set the pop-up to hidden at first if you need to.

```js
$('#btnAddLot').click(function (e) {
    alert('hey');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 800
}, {
    height: 600
}, {
    modal: true
}, {
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('#dialog').show();
        $("#dialog").html(varLot);
        $("textarea").jqte();
        //$("#dialog").append($(section).html());
    },
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='dialog' style="display:none"><b>Lot Title: </b> 
    <input type="text" id="txtlottitle" style="width:500px;" value="Lot Title" />
    <textarea id="lotstextarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="ADD" id="btnAddLot" class="bluebutton" style="float:right;" />
    <br />
    <div id="lottypes">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:width: 80px;"><b>Lot Types: </b>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="rdoitemlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Item Lot" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Item Lot - Bid at Item level, compete at Lot level(collect item pricing during bidding.)</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="rdobasketlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Basket - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(collect item pricing post bidding.)</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="rdobasketwithnoitem" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket with No Items" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Basket with No Items - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(Do not collect item pricing.)</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Improve Bid By:</td>
            <td><span id="lblimprovebidsby"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="lblbiddecrement">Bid Decrement</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="txtbiddecrement" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Protect the lead bid with front buffer of : </span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="txtfrontbuffer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Protect the lead bid with back buffer of : </span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="txtbackbuffer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Can participants submit tie bids : </span>

            </td>
            <td><span id="lbltiebids"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        var varLot = '<b>Lot Title: </b> <input type="text" id="txtlottitle" style="width:500px;" value="Lot Title" /> <textarea id="lotstextarea"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="ADD" id="btnAddLot" class="bluebutton" style="float:right;"/> <br /> <div id="lottypes"> <table> <tr> <td style="width: 80px;"><b>Lot Types: </b></td><td> <table> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdoitemlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Item Lot" /></td><td>Item Lot - Bid at Item level, compete at Lot level(collect item pricing during bidding.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdobasketlot" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket"/></td><td>Basket - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(collect item pricing post bidding.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> <tr><td><table><tr><td><input id="rdobasketwithnoitem" name="lottype" type="radio" value="Basket with No Items" /></td><td> Basket with No Items - Bid at Lot level, compete Lot level(Do not collect item pricing.)</td></tr></table> </td></tr> </table></td> </tr> </table> </div> <hr /> <table> <tr> <td>Improve Bid By: </td><td><span id="lblimprovebidsby"></span></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span id="lblbiddecrement">Bid Decrement</span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtbiddecrement" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Protect the lead bid with front buffer of : </span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtfrontbuffer" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Protect the lead bid with back buffer of : </span></td><td><input type="number" id="txtbackbuffer" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td><span >Can participants submit tie bids : </span></td><td><span id="lbltiebids"></span></td> </tr> </table>'
        $("div#dialog").on("click","#btnAddLot",function () {
            alert('hey');

        });
        $("#dialog").html(varLot).hide().dialog({
        //you might put your options here
        });



    })
```